# Junit mock generic class as method parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, atlas

I am writing unit test and verify the method call within it through Junit framework. The methods which are implemented by me are stated below which is in my code base :

```
AtlasBaseClient.API api = new AtlasBaseClient.API("api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs","PUT",Response.Status.OK);

1.     client.callAPI(api, (Class<?>) null, (Object) objectMapper.writeValueAsString(type), null);
2.     client.callAPI(api, (Class<?>) null, object, null);
```

The library declaration of above methods is :

```
public <T> T callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.API api, Class<T> responseType, Object requestObject, String... params) throws AtlasServiceException {
    return this.callAPIWithResource(api, this.getResource(api, params), requestObject, responseType);
  }
```

Now, I am writing unit test and want to verify whether these methods are called or not and for that code snippet which I am trying looks like

```
verify(client, times(1)).callAPI(any(AtlasBaseClient.API.class), (Class<?>) null, any(Object.class), any());
```

But as per Junit framework if one of the parameters si passed through matcher than all other should also which is making test to fail.

Comment: Can you also provide the error message to clarify the problem.

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

Answer (score 0):

```
verify(client, times(2)).callAPI(any(AtlasBaseClient.API.class), Mockito.<Class>isNull(), any(Object.class), any());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use matchers in a `verify` test **all** the arguments need to be a matcher, which is what `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` means.

You're explicitly testing the second parameter for `null`, it should be `Mockito.isNull()` or something similar.

i.e.

```java
verify(client, times(1)).callAPI(any(AtlasBaseClient.API.class), isNull(), any(Object.class), any());
```

Comment: This is failing at compile due to method overloading. Below are two method public <T> T callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.API api, Class<T> responseType, Object requestObject, String... params) throws AtlasServiceException {
  }

  public <T> T callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.API api, GenericType<T> responseType, Object requestObject, String... params) throws AtlasServiceException {
  }

Comment: @OPTIMUS: Then you can cast the second parameter to whichever type you're planning to call for, or use `Mockito.<Class>isNull()` or similar.  (Although I'd expect your IDE would both suggest and resolve that for you if you click on its advice for the issue.)

Comment: Thanks it worked.    verify(client, times(2)).callAPI(any(AtlasBaseClient.API.class), Mockito.<Class>isNull(), any(Object.class), any());

Comment: @OPTIMUS Cool, mark the answer as correct, it got downvoted for some reason despite being the solution.